# Laravel 5 override summernote Image upload

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5, image-upload, summernote

I want to override image upload in summernote with laravel 5 method ajax, but I cant get it to work.

Here's my php method

```
public function ajaxImage()
{
    $file = Input::file('image');
    $destinationPath = public_path();
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    if(Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename)) {
        echo $destinationPath.$filename;
    }
}
```

and here's my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#description').summernote({
                height: 300,

                onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable) {
                    sendFile(files[0], editor, welEditable);
                }
            });
            function sendFile(file, editor, welEditable) {
                var  data = new FormData();
                data.append("file", file);
                var url = '/articles/ajaximage';
                $.ajax({
                    data: data,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(url) {
                        alert('Success');
                        editor.insertImage(welEditable, url);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

and i get an error in the console of:

POST http://marcus.dev/articles/ajaximage 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Find your solution with that .... 
http://www.somrat.info/summarnote-image-upload-with-laravel/

Comment: Please, do not add _Solved_ in a question title.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74304884/how-to-save-and-edit-images-by-summmernote-editor-in-laravel-8 Please read this question and help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how.. its a

> "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken" problem.

Source: http://laravel.io/forum/01-30-2015-laravel5-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken

I added this in the header of my main view:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

and this in the script before `document.ready`

```js
    $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
```

and finally the php method:

```php
    Route::post('ajaximage', function(){

       $file = Request::file('file');
       $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/';
       $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
       $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
       echo url().'/uploads/'.$filename;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

As for summernote version 0.6.9 we cant use editor in the callback function anymore.

instead of

```
editor.insertImage(welEditable, url);
```

I used

```
$('#summernote').summernote('editor.insertImage', url);
```

I dont know if there's a cleaner version but it seems to work.

Comment: For summernote v0.8.11, the correct code is: `$('#summernote').summernote('insertImage', url);` [documentation](https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#insertimage). Also note that the `onImageInsert` needs to be inside a `callbacks` object now: `$('#summernote').summernote({ callbacks: { onImageInsert: ... } });`