# summmernote editor Issues in Laravel

Tags: laravel-8, summernote

I am saving some images which created & upload by Summernote Editor in my Laravel application and it getting saved properly. But when I want to edit the content, sometimes I am getting the content from DB and load it into Summernote Editor.

But Most of the cases, the page loading & loading ..... And The content not loads. Sometimes loads properly, but see the string as the attached image below.

[image]

```
 <textarea name="long_desc" class="form-control" id="summernote" rows="20">{{ $portfolio_data->long_desc}}</textarea>
```

How to solve this error!!

Comment: The string is a base64 representation of the image uploaded using input type file (i.e Featured Image). Could you also upload your entire code snippet ?

Comment: have you solve this issue.. actualy i am facing one issue.. closing tag of image not save in table..

Comment: @MiliDubey in controler dd($request->full_text) die the whole data including image tag.. but when save in db then closing tag of image not save

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<textarea name="long_desc" class="form-control" id="summernote" rows="20">{!! $portfolio_data->long_desc !!}</textarea>
```

Comment: I have already tried this way, but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this cdn

[Summernote CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/summernote/0.8.16)

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: summernote cdn url not find

Comment: Link solved check again and copy the first CDN file v0.8.16

Comment: I have used this cdn before you noted. There is also some issues!